# Crawl and scrape a complete site with scrapy

Tags: python, web-scraping, scrapy, web-crawler

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request

#scrapy crawl jobs9 -o jobs9.csv -t csv
class JobsSpider(scrapy.Spider):
name = "jobs9"
allowed_domains = ["vapedonia.com"]
start_urls = ["https://www.vapedonia.com/7-principiantes-kit-s-de-inicio-", 
              "https://www.vapedonia.com/10-cigarrillos-electronicos-", 
              "https://www.vapedonia.com/11-mods-potencia-", 
              "https://www.vapedonia.com/12-consumibles", 
              "https://www.vapedonia.com/13-baterias", 
              "https://www.vapedonia.com/23-e-liquidos", 
              "https://www.vapedonia.com/26-accesorios", 
              "https://www.vapedonia.com/31-atomizadores-reparables", 
              "https://www.vapedonia.com/175-alquimia-", 
              "https://www.vapedonia.com/284-articulos-en-liquidacion"]

def parse(self, response):
    products = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-container clearfix"]')
    for product in products:
        image = product.xpath('div[@class="center_block"]/a/img/@src').extract_first()
        link = product.xpath('div[@class="center_block"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        name = product.xpath('div[@class="right_block"]/p/a/text()').extract_first()
        price = product.xpath('div[@class="right_block"]/div[@class="content_price"]/span[@class="price"]/text()').extract_first().encode("utf-8")
        yield{'Image' : image, 'Link' : link, 'Name': name, 'Price': price}
        
    relative_next_url = response.xpath('//*[@id="pagination_next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
    absolute_next_url = "https://www.vapedonia.com" + str(relative_next_url)
    yield Request(absolute_next_url, callback=self.parse)
```

with that code, I scrape correctly the products of a page and its subpages. All pages are crawled.

If I want to scrape the whole site, I must put the categories URLs manually in "start_urls". The gppd thing should me crawl those urls to make that crawl dynamic.

How can I mix crawling with scraping beyond the simple paginated crawl?

Thank you.

**Now, I improve my code, here's the new code:**

```
import scrapy
from scrapy import Request
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor

#scrapy crawl jobs10 -o jobs10.csv -t csv
class JobsSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
name = "jobs10"
allowed_domains = ["vapedonia.com"]
start_urls = ["https://www.vapedonia.com/"]

rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r"https://www.vapedonia.com/\d+.*",)), callback='parse_category'), )

def parse_category(self, response):
    products = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-container clearfix"]')
    for product in products:
        image = product.xpath('div[@class="center_block"]/a/img/@src').extract_first()
        link = product.xpath('div[@class="center_block"]/a/@href').extract_first()
        name = product.xpath('div[@class="right_block"]/p/a/text()').extract_first()
        price = product.xpath('div[@class="right_block"]/div[@class="content_price"]/span[@class="price"]/text()').extract_first().encode("utf-8")
        yield{'Image' : image, 'Link' : link, 'Name': name, 'Price': price}
```

The changes I've made are the following:

1- I import Crawlspider, Rule and LinkExtractor

```
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
```

2- the jobSpider class does not inherit from "scrapy.Spider" anymore. It now inherits from scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider (which has been exported in the previous step)

3- "starts_urls" is not composed from a static list of urls anymore, we just take the domain name, so

```
start_urls = ["https://www.vapedonia.com/7-principiantes-kit-s-de-inicio-", 
    "https://www.vapedonia.com/10-cigarrillos-electronicos-", 
    "https://www.vapedonia.com/11-mods-potencia-", 
    "https://www.vapedonia.com/12-consumibles", 
    "https://www.vapedonia.com/13-baterias", 
    "https://www.vapedonia.com/23-e-liquidos", 
    "https://www.vapedonia.com/26-accesorios", 
    "https://www.vapedonia.com/31-atomizadores-reparables", 
    "https://www.vapedonia.com/175-alquimia-", 
    "https://www.vapedonia.com/284-articulos-en-liquidacion"]
```

is replaced by

```
start_urls = ["https://www.vapedonia.com/"]
```

4- we put the rules

```
rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r"https://www.vapedonia.com/\d+.*",)), callback='parse_category'), )
```

we don't call "parse" anymore "but parse_category"

5- the previous pagination crawling disappear. So, the next code simply disappear

```
relative_next_url = response.xpath('//*[@id="pagination_next"]/a/@href').extract_first()
absolute_next_url = "https://www.vapedonia.com" + str(relative_next_url)
yield Request(absolute_next_url, callback=self.parse)
```

So as I see it and it seems very logical, pagination crawling process is replaced by url crawling process.

But... it does not work and even the "price" field which worked with encode("utf-8") does not work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

You need to use a CrawlSpider with rules in this case. Below is a simple translated one of your scraper

```
class JobsSpider(scrapy.spiders.CrawlSpider):
    name = "jobs9"
    allowed_domains = ["vapedonia.com"]
    start_urls = ["https://www.vapedonia.com"]

    rules = (Rule(LinkExtractor(allow=(r"https://www.vapedonia.com/\d+.*",)), callback='parse_category'), )

    def parse_category(self, response):
        products = response.xpath('//div[@class="product-container clearfix"]')
        for product in products:
            image = product.xpath('div[@class="center_block"]/a/img/@src').extract_first()
            link = product.xpath('div[@class="center_block"]/a/@href').extract_first()
            name = product.xpath('div[@class="right_block"]/p/a/text()').extract_first()
            price = product.xpath(
                'div[@class="right_block"]/div[@class="content_price"]/span[@class="price"]/text()').extract_first().encode(
                "utf-8")
            yield {'Image': image, 'Link': link, 'Name': name, 'Price': price}
```

Look at different spiders on https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/spiders.html

[image: scrapy run]

Comment: Thanks. I've changed my code at the beginning of the page. I understand that instead of doing a "pagination crawling", I have to do a "urls pagination". But it still does not work.

Comment: I ran the code before posting and it was yielding items, what is the issue you are facing?

Comment: but was it crawling correctly all the site urls? I'm facing 2 issues: 1- it doesn't crawl (it only scraps the first page products), 2- the price won't work anymore (I had resolved that issue applying a .encode(utf-8)).

Comment: Thank you very much, Tarun. This is really great from you.  On my part, I will try to understand why it's not working. May be I find it before you do and I put it here. Just one thing: I'm using Notepad++. Is it a too simple editor to use? should I better use a good IDE like pycharm for example? I'm always struggling with the spaces think (I can't use tabs).

Comment: uhmmm!! this answer's not coming!

Comment: @eric5037, see the screenshot I added to answer, i just checked it crawls other pages also. You can page 3,14 for consumbiles category.

Comment: consumibles category (https://www.vapedonia.com/12-consumibles) has 14 pages. visiting all sites we can extract more than 300 products. do you really extract all that? if so, why is working for you and not for me