# Scrapy : Preserving a website

Tags: scrapy, archiving

I'm trying to save a copy the `pyparsing` project  on `wikispaces.com` before they take wikispaces down at the end of the month.

It seems odd (perhaps my version of google is broken ^_^) but I can't find any examples of duplicating/copying a site as. That is, as one views it upon a browser. SO has [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36838995/958580) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46356948/958580) on the topic but they are just saving the text, strictly the HTML/DOM structure, for the site. Unless I'm mistaken these asnwers do not appear to save the images/header link files/javascript and related information necessary to render the page. Further examples I have seen are more concerned with extraction of parts of the page and not duplicating it as is.

I was wondering if anyone had any experience with this sort of thing or could point me to a useful blog/doc somewhere. I've used `WinHTTrack` in the past but the `robots.txt` or the `pyparsing.wikispaces.com/auth/` route are preventing it from running properly and I figured I'd get some `scrapy` experience in.

For those interested to see what I have tried thus far. Here is my crawl spider implementation, that acknowledges the `robots.txt` file

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from pathlib import Path
from scrapy.linkextractors import LinkExtractor
from scrapy.spiders import CrawlSpider, Rule


class PyparsingSpider(CrawlSpider):
 name = 'pyparsing'
 allowed_domains = ['pyparsing.wikispaces.com']
 start_urls = ['http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/']

 rules = (
     Rule(LinkExtractor(), callback='parse_item', follow=True),
 )

 def parse_item(self, response):
#   i = {}
#   #i['domain_id'] = response.xpath('//input[@id="sid"]/@value').extract()
#   #i['name'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="name"]').extract()
#   #i['description'] = response.xpath('//div[@id="description"]').extract()
#   return i
  page = urlparse(response.url)
  path = Path(page.netloc)/Path("" if page.path == "/" else page.path[1:])
  if path.parent : path.parent.mkdir(parents = True, exist_ok=True) # Creates the folder
  path = path.with_suffix(".html")
  with open(path, 'wb') as file:
   file.write(response.body)
```

Trying the same thing with the sitemap spider is similar. The first [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36837594/958580) link provides an implementation with a plain spider.

```
import scrapy
from scrapy.spiders import SitemapSpider
from urllib.parse import urlparse
from pathlib import Path

class PyParsingSiteMap(SitemapSpider) :

 name = "pyparsing"
 sitemap_urls = [ 
                  'http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/sitemap.xml', 
#                   'http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com/robots.txt', 
                ]
 allowed_domains = ['pyparsing.wikispaces.com']
 start_urls = ['http://pyparsing.wikispaces.com'] # "/home"
 custom_settings = {
  "ROBOTSTXT_OBEY" : False
 }

 def parse(self, response) :
  page = urlparse(response.url)
  path = Path(page.netloc)/Path("" if page.path == "/" else page.path[1:])
  if path.parent : path.parent.mkdir(parents = True, exist_ok=True) # Creates the folder
  path = path.with_suffix(".html")
  with open(path, 'wb') as file:
   file.write(response.body)
```

None of these spiders collect more then the HTML structure

Also I have found that the links, `<a href="...">...</a>`, that are saved do not appear to point to proper *relative* paths. Atleast, when opening the saved files, the links point to a path relative to the hard drive and not relative to the file. While opening a page via `http.server` the links point to dead locations, presumably the `.html` extension is the trouble here. It might be necessary to remap/replace links in the stored structure.

Comment: Pyparsing is no longer hosted on wikispaces.com. Go to https://github.com/pyparsing/pyparsing

Comment: I didn't get the spider working in the end so I'm glad it's moved to Github. It's a really nice library by the way. I've been writing a PyQt application to draw out the parser/grammar tree one generates with PyLens, the code is still quite rough but if you're interested I'll post it up when it's a touch neater.

Comment: If you do this, call `streamline()` on the top-level element before graphing - this will  consolidate elements like `And([And([And([A, B]), C]), D])` (as created by successive '+' operations) to `And([A, B, C, D])`